# Lucene creating duplicate indexes

Tags: indexing, lucene.net

I created an app using lucene. The server winded up throwing out of memory errors because I was new'in up an IndexSeacher for every search in the app. The garbage collector couldn't keep up.

I just got done implementing a singleton approach and now there are multiple indexes being created.

[image]

Any clue why this is happening? IndexWriter is what I am keeping static. I get IndexSearchers from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have multiple indexes, you just have multiple segments. Lucene splits the index up into segments over time, although you can compact it if you want.

See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#What_are_Segments.3F) and [here](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/fileformats.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

You also probably want to "new up" one IndexSearcher and pass it around, seems like you are creating the index every time here.